# Angular material side nav mode not working

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I have the angular 6 application which has got a main sidenav container. in one of the page i am using a simple sidenav. evertything is working but the sidenav mode is not working as expected. Though i set the mode to 'side' it is using 'over' as the default.

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav [mode]="sidenavOption.mode"
                 position="start"
                 [opened]="sidenavOption.open"
                 appKvpDashboardSidenav
                 #leftsidenav>
        <app-left-sidenav [sidenav]="leftsidenav"
                          [isEditing]="isEditing"
                          [kvpDashboardId]="kvpDashboardId"
                          [kvpModelId]="kvpModelId"
                          [kvpModelPath]="kvpModelPath">
        </app-left-sidenav>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content fxLayout="row">
        <app-kvp-sidenav-toggle (toggleClicked)="toggleSidenav()"></app-kvp-sidenav-toggle>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

I am using the below setting in .ts file

```
sidenavoption.mode = 'side'
```

sidenavoption.open = true

Can anyone help how to make this work?

Comment: Case matters - 'sidenavOption vs 'sidenavoption'. Either this is your problem, or your example is sloppy and needs correcting.

Comment: example is sloppy.